# SAS to R code First and last functions

Tags: r, sas, output

I am relatively new to SAS and am working on converting a code from SAS to R. 
I came across this snippet which has me a little confused.

```
data A ; set B;
by date id Units;
retain Total;
if first.id and last.id then do;
Total=Units;
output; 
end;
else do ;
if  first.id then Total=Units;
else Total=sum(Total,Units);
if last.id then output;
end;
run;
```

If my understanding of this code is right, this snippet outputs a data set called A that is a union of (in SQL terminology) all fist and last occurrences of id and the last occurence of the id. Am I right? What is the purpose of the By statement then? I tried going through the SAS help but I still am confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `by` statement is responsible for the creation of the `last` and `first` variables this operates based on.  Without it you don't have access to those variables.

What this code does is sums over the variable, similar to

```
proc sql;
select id, sum(units) as total
from b
group by id;
quit;
```

Basically, if you are on a single row (one row for that ID), Total=Units; otherwise, on the first row, set total=units, then for each additional row, add units to total, and then on the last row for that ID, output a row with the total.